# Looping through partial sections of an array

Tags: python

I have code from a tutorial that does this:

```
elements = []

for i in range(0, 6):
    print "Adding %d to the list." % i
    # append is a function that lists understand
    elements.append(i)

for i in elements:
    print "Element was: %d" % i
```

However, if I only want to print from elements[0] to elements[4], how is this achieved?

Comment: I think you mean "list". In Python, an "array" is something [completely different](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html).

Comment: I must have gotten them confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using *slicing*:

```
for i in elements[0:5]:
    print "Element was: %d" % i
```

The end index is not included in the range, so you need to bump it up from 4 to 5.

The starting zero can be omitted:

```
for i in elements[:5]:
    print "Element was: %d" % i
```

For more information, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: Thanks. *Slicing* is the word I'm looking for.

Comment: @stanigator: You're welcome. Please see the updated answer for the link to a good SO post that explains slicing.

Comment: Ya, also saw that. Read Python's official documentation about it too afterwards.